# Page refreshes on clicking select button in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Whenever i try to click Search buttong or select button within Gridview that it loads and scrolls up whole page. I want to stay it in place. How ?

code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtComplaintSubject" runat="server" CssClass="textField_width"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch"  CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Search" 
             ValidationGroup="AdminRole" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />

             <asp:GridView ID="gridViewComplaints" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridViewComplaints_SelectedIndexChanged">
              <EmptyDataRowStyle BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Red" BorderWidth="0px" />
               <EmptyDataTemplate>
                  No Data Found for this Input. Try Again.
               </EmptyDataTemplate> 
             <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selected-row" BackColor="YellowGreen" ForeColor="white" />
             </asp:GridView>



protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ManageComposedLetter mngCompLetter = new ManageComposedLetter();
        DataTable dt = mngCompLetter.FillGridView_Complaints(txtComplaintSubject.Text);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gridViewComplaints.DataSource = dt;
            gridViewComplaints.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
            gridViewComplaints.DataSource = dt;
            gridViewComplaints.DataBind();
            int totalcolums = gridViewComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            gridViewComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            gridViewComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            gridViewComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = totalcolums;
            gridViewComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data Found";
        }
```

}

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. Check [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stay at the same position after page refresh just add

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"
```

at the top of your aspx file, so it will look like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use update panel...

you can look from here

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think u could also use if(!Page.IsPostBack) in page load. It could be easyer for this problem. (But i recommend u all to learn update panel ofc)